# Getting segmentation fault (core dumped) and don't understand why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to reverse a string, my program will compile and do everything it is suppose to do, however, when I run the application I'm getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, I understand what the error means, but I don't understand where it's coming from:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char tmp, *src, *dst;
    size_t len;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        if (len > 1)
        {
            src = str;
            dst = src + len - 1;

            while (src < dst)
            {
                tmp = *src;
                *src++ = *dst;
                *dst++ = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str[] = {"a", "ab", "abc", "test", "another test"};
    int i;
    char s[10000];
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]); i++)
    {
        strcpy (s, str[i]);
        printf("Original: %s", str[i]);
        printf("Reversed: %s", reverse(s));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting a segmentation fault, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Begin by using a debugger to find out *where* the crash happens in your code. Then check the values of all involved variables. If you still can't figure it out yourself, then please edit your question to tell *us* those details.

Comment: Its time to use debugger. For this small program it won't be difficult at all. If you have any specific question about crash dump update the details.

Comment: Your algorithm is slightly wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `src` and `dst` pointers are moving in the same direction, so `src` never "catches" `dst`. Eventually pointers go past the allowed region of memory, causing undefined behavior, which results in segmentation fault.

You need to decrement `dst` instead of incrementing it:

```
while (src < dst)
{
    tmp = *src;
    *src++ = *dst;
    *dst-- = tmp;
} //    ^^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Xmn4fV)